# как поменять местами строки в массиве?

Tags: swift, xcode

```
Есть такой массив: var textArraу: [String] = ["aa", "fff", "aaa", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]
 
Нужно такой:var textArraу: [String] = ["aa", "aaa" "bbbb",  "fff", "333" , "5555555"]
```

Comment: А вы сами как-то пробовали делать? Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Сортировка строк, нет?

Comment: через цикл нужно, я даже незнаю как зделать:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае можно использовать как минимум 3 способа - сортировка, обмен местами и перемещение, выбор способа зависит от задачи

```
var textArray: [String] = ["aa", "fff", "aaa", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]

print("original\t\t\(textArray)")

// 1 sort

textArray.sort { s1, s2 in
    s1[s1.startIndex].isLetter ? s1 < s2 : s1 > s2
}

print("sort\t\t\t\(textArray)")

// 2 swap

textArray = ["aa", "fff", "aaa", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]

textArray.swapAt(1, 2)
print("swap step 1\t\(textArray)")

textArray.swapAt(2, 3)
print("swap step 2\t\(textArray)")

// 3 move

textArray = ["aa", "fff", "aaa", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]

let fff = textArray.remove(at: 1)
print("move step 1\t\(textArray)")
textArray.insert(fff, at: 3)
print("move step 2\t\(textArray)")
```

Вывод

```
original    ["aa", "fff", "aaa", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]
sort        ["aa", "aaa", "bbbb", "fff", "5555555", "333"]
swap step 1 ["aa", "aaa", "fff", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]
swap step 2 ["aa", "aaa", "bbbb", "fff", "333", "5555555"]
move step 1 ["aa", "aaa", "bbbb", "333", "5555555"]
move step 2 ["aa", "aaa", "bbbb", "fff", "333", "5555555"]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ErwinRoomm если ответ устроил, поставьте возле него галку